# Connect to Elasticsearch through an SSH tunnel

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ssh, rest, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create an SSH session and connect to elasticsearch that is in EC2 instance. I am using this code to do that but it is failing with

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
ElasticsearchException[]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2078)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1684)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.LicenseClient.getBasicStatus(LicenseClient.java:191)
I am trying to create an SSH tunnel and connect to elasticsearch that is in EC2 instance. I am using this code to do that but it is failing with
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
ElasticsearchException[]; nested: ExecutionException[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]; nested: ConnectException[Connection refused];
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2078)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1684)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.LicenseClient.getBasicStatus(LicenseClient.java:191)
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
        Session session = null;
        String sshKeyFile = "/path/testSSH.pem";

        try {
            JSch jsc = new JSch();
            jsc.addIdentity(sshKeyFile);
            session = jsc.getSession("user", "ec2-instance", 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();

            int i = session.setPortForwardingL(30000, "localhost", 22, null);

            final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user_name", "pass"));

            RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200));
            builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(a -> a.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
            RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
            GetBasicStatusResponse response = client.license().getBasicStatus(RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            response.isEligibleToStartBasic();
            System.out.println(response.toString());

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Probably I am missing something. Any help here please.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there is `Connection refused` exception, it means either:

- Wrong hostname, port in your connection string
- The Elasticsearch port is not even listened on the server side
- Some kind of firewall blocking the connection

You are saying that Elasticsearch is installed inside EC2 instance but in your code, the connection is connecting to `localhost`on port `9200`. I assume that you are running this piece of code on your local machine and you suppose to connect to the host of the EC2 instance, not localhost.

Comment: I opened a ssh session where on my EC2 instance and Localhost is the host in the EC2 instance to connect to Elasticsearch. After creating an ssh tunnel, how can we call the ES api to connect to the ES running in EC2?